# Securely passing iam role in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm able to use AWS plugin to do it.

```
withAWS(role:<TOKEN>, roleAccount:'XXXXXXXXXX', region:<AWS_REGION>) {
   {
      sh "aws <operation>"
   }
}
```

Currently, passing the token in WithAWS directly.

What is the solution to pass IAM role securely using credentials to connect with AWS?

Answer (score 1):

When your AWS creds are coming back dynamically from an assumed role, you need to use Groovy variables to pass them to your steps.

```
script {
    ASSUME_ROLE_ARN='arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/jenkins'
    TEMP_ROLE = sh (
        script: "aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${ASSUME_ROLE_ARN} --role-session-name jenkins-dev",
        returnStdout: true
        ).trim()
    TEMP_ROLE = readJSON text: "${TEMP_ROLE}"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = TEMP_ROLE.Credentials.AccessKeyId
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = TEMP_ROLE.Credentials.SecretAccessKey
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = TEMP_ROLE.Credentials.SessionToken
    wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID],[password: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN],[password: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY]]]) {
        withEnv(['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=TEMP_ROLE.Credentials.SessionTokens']){
            echo "TOKEN: ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}"
            echo "KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
            echo "ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
        }
    }
}
```

I added the wrapper to mask the credentials from the console log, since we don't get the default credentials handling. I tried a couple of the jenkins plugins that do password masking, but they seem not to work with pipeline jobs.

EDIT: you will need to install the 'mask-password' plugin for my little wrap() command to work.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/

Answer (score 0):

If your credentials are stored in Jenkins, you could use the [`credentials`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment) helper function to unpack them into the environment and pass them as variables.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            environment {
                IAM_INFO=credentials('iam-role-credentials')
                AWS_REGION='us-west-2'
            }

            steps {
                withAWS(role: env.IAM_INFO_PSW,
                        roleAccount: env.IAM_INFO_USR,
                        region: env.AWS_REGION) {
                    sh "aws help"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track by using WithAWS wrapper. Here is how I assume a role for code that needs elevated access.

Example:

```
myRole = "valid AWS role name" <- last part of valid AWS Arn
myRegion = "valid AWS region" <- useful for other AWS functions but not needed for role assumption
myRoleAccount = "valid AWS account number"
myExternalId = "if role has externalId set, include it here"
myDuration = 3600 <- limit to 1 hour

WithAWS(role: myRole, region: myRegion, roleAccount: myRoleAccount, externalId: myExternalId, duration: myDuration ){
  some groovy code
}
```

I find withAWS() to be very useful overall. More information here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/#plugin-content-withaws

I hope this helps.