# Declarative Pipeline Jenkinsfile: Export variables out of sh call

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I export some variables out of an `sh` block so they can be used in later stages?

The following does not give me any errors but the values are never available as environment variables in later stages.

```
steps {
     sh """
          ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE=\$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::${env.NON_PROD_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/${env.AWS_ROLE}" --role-session-name "${env.AWS_ROLE_SESSION}" --duration-seconds 3600)
          ${env.ACCESS_KEY_ID}=\$(echo \$ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE | jq --raw-output '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
          ${env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}=\$(echo \$ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE | jq --raw-output '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
          ${env.SESSION_TOKEN}=\$(echo \$ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE | jq --raw-output '.Credentials.SessionToken')

          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${ACCESS_KEY_ID},AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${SECRET_ACCESS_KEY},AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${SESSION_TOKEN}"
          printenv | sort
        """
      }
```

Comment: can you use a `withAWS` block? https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/#plugin-content-withaws I think I would prefer to have freshly minted credentials every time I needed them, rather than save them for later. You might also leak secrets into the Jenkins log

Comment: I posted an answer here that is cleaner, it shows how to use an AWS IAM assumed role, and retrieve the credentials with Groovy variables:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74214392/2752340

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working but I cannot say it is elegant, if someone has a better\cleaner answer I would happily accept it.

Here is my solution:

```
stage("Authenticate To Non-Prod Account") {
      steps {
        script {
          aws_credentials = sh(script: """
            ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE=\$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::${env.NON_PROD_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/${env.AWS_ROLE}" --role-session-name "${env.AWS_ROLE_SESSION}" --duration-seconds 3600)
            ACCESS_KEY_ID=\$(echo \$ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE | jq --raw-output '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
            SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\$(echo \$ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE | jq --raw-output '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
            SESSION_TOKEN=\$(echo \$ASSUME_ROLE_RESPONSE | jq --raw-output '.Credentials.SessionToken')

            echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\$ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\$SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\$SESSION_TOKEN"
          """, returnStdout: true)

          env.ACCESS_KEY_ID = aws_credentials.split(',')[0].split('=')[1].trim()
          env.AWS_SECRET_KEY = aws_credentials.split(',')[1].split('=')[1].trim()
          env.SESSION_TOKEN = aws_credentials.split(',')[2].split('=')[1].trim()
        }
      }
    }
```

I am answering as I have read a heap of posts which have suggested ideas that didnt work for me so this, for now, is the best option I have for authentication to AWS and ensuring the credentials are available in subsequent stages.

Comment: An easier way to do this would be to just retain the JSON output from `aws sts assume-role` in the assigned `aws_credentials` Groovy var, and then parse that in Groovy, and assign it to your environment variables. It would be something like one-third of the code you have in this answer. However, this is otherwise close to the normal pattern for achieving this goal.

Comment: If you have a working example with groovy and can post it as an accepted answer, please do. I am trying to do as little with groovy as possible, but you are right, doing more in bash and then some in groovy just ends up verbose.

Comment: If you have a redacted/sanitized snippet of the `stdout` from the `aws sts assume-role`, then I could write something up for that.

Answer (score 0):

To export vars out of sh try using this:

```
env.var = sh (returnStdout: true, script: ''' SOME SH COMMAND ''').trim()
```

This will export your bash values to groovy variables in fact it can push the vars to the environment.

Answer (score 0):

For future people looking at this thread this worked for me and set it globally, simply set AWS_ASSUME_ROLE_ARN in the environment as your desired 'assume role':

```
script {
    def aws_credentials = readJSON text: sh (returnStdout: true, script: """ aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${AWS_ASSUME_ROLE_ARN} --role-session-name Session --query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" --output json """).trim()
    env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = aws_credentials[0]
    env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = aws_credentials[1]
    env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = aws_credentials[2]
}
```